# Codefirst and creating database problem because of authentication

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I was using Codefirst on ASP.NET Core MVC, I tried to secure my SQL. I changed some settings (example *disable "sa" user).

Now I can't create new databases or change tables in Visual Studio.

I enabled the "sa" user again but it didn't work.

How can I fix this?

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. SqlException: Cannot open database "testdatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '...@gmail.com'. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide some more information about what error you are getting? It's difficult to say why it's not working without a little more specific information.

Comment: that is ContosoUniversity example: SqlException: Invalid object name 'Person'.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__108_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)

Comment: Did you read the error? There is a login issue, and likely your problem is entirely unrelated to your question.

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot, but if you're willing to scrap your existing database, and you're using localdb, try opening the nuget package manager console and entering `sqllocaldb p` then `sqllocaldb d` then `sqllocaldb c` This will pause, delete and create a new localdb.